# Simple.Data.SimpleQuery

Tags: simple.data

I am new to .Net Dynamics and using Simple.Data for the first time in a tiny project. I need to query data and assign the records returned to a DropDownList but I get a list of "Simple.Data.SimpleQuery" items in my ddl. The code snippet is below.

```
    var show_crm = Database.Open();
    var sites = show_crm.tblSites.Select(show_crm.tblSites.SiteID, show_crm.tblSites.SiteName);
    DropDownList1.DataSource = sites;
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = sites.SiteID;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = sites.SiteName;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Select just creates a query, you need to run it by calling ToList(). Also, you probably need to set the DataValueField and DataTextField properties to the names of the properties.

```
var show_crm = Database.Open();
var sites = show_crm.tblSites.Select(show_crm.tblSites.SiteID, show_crm.tblSites.SiteName);
DropDownList1.DataSource = sites.ToList<Site>();
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SiteID";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SiteName";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

I've never used Simple.Data in a Web Forms project, so I am not 100% sure the data binding will work with the dynamic properties. If you still have a problem, please comment on this answer.

Comment: Thanks Mark but still have problem. It comes up with the following error. DataBinding: 'Simple.Data.SimpleRecord' does not contain a property with the name 'SiteName'.

Comment: I thought that might happen. Web Forms obviously isn't a fan of dynamics. You'll need to use a Site class with SiteID and SiteName properties, and sites.ToList<Site>(); I'll edit my answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks Mark! The above idea helped alot. Created a class with the specific properties and it worked. Hurrah! Going to complete my first tiny project in Simple.Data.

Comment: Thought it might help some novice like me. Here is the Sites class @mark-rendle advised about. `public class Sites
    {
        private int _siteId;
        private string _siteName;

        public int SiteID
        {
            get
            {
                return _siteId;
            }
            set
            {
                _siteId = value;
            }
        }

        public string SiteName
        {
            get
            {
                return _siteName;
            }
            set
            {
                _siteName = value;
            }
        }
    }`